# Java Swing - flickering Canvas graphics

Tags: java, swing, canvas, repaint

I have to write a simple Java app which can load pictures, show it in a GUI form, allow the user to apply some transformation, and show the transformed picture.
My solution is working fine, but the UI is flickering a bit, because the repaint method called too often (for example when the user scaling the image with a JSlider)

My code looks like this:

```
public class ImageCanvas extends Canvas
{
    private BufferedImage image;
    // ...

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        if(image != null)
        {
             // I draw out the image...
        }
    }

    public void setImage(BufferedImage image)
    {
        this.image = image;
        this.repaint();
    }

    public void setRotation(double rotation)
    {
        this.rotation = rotation;
        this.repaint();
    }

    public void setScale(double scaleX, double scaleY) 
    { 
       //set the scaling field, then repaint ....
    }    

    // and so on...
}
```

And, of course, I have an ImageCanvas control on my main UI, and I simply call the public methods (see for example the "setRotation" method above) which repaint the canvas area. I know it's a simple question, but I don't even find a DoubleBuffered property on the Canvas...

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Double buffering is built-in for Swing (i.e. JComponent derived) classes.

If you want built-in double-buffering, you should extend JPanel rather than Canvas, and override `paintComponent`, not `paint`.

Comment: There are no JCanvas...Should I use JPanel then?

Comment: @asdfghjkl: yes, JPanel and override `paintComponent`, not `paint`. Answer above edited for correction.

Comment: Okay, it works with JPanel. I don't know, if this could be a "best practice" in Swing or is it a hack, but thanks.

Comment: @asdfghjkl: this is definitely "best practice" and no hack.

Comment: Why does everyone always extend JPanel instead of JComponent, which feels a lot cleaner to me.

Comment: @Martijn: I do it out of preference. JPanel's are opaque by default, a background color can be set once and forgotten via setBackground(). JComponent would work well too though.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `JPanel` than go for it. Please make sure you are not overriding the `JPanel.paint` method, override `JPanel.paintComponent` instead.
See this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html) for details.

Answer (score -1):

Usually graphic lags in these applications can be caused by setting a empty variable at the top of the script, then changing its value, then waiting for the repaint to update it. You could try changing the:

```
    setRotation(double rotation);
```

so that it rotates the image in that method.

Just a general thing I happen to see while dealing with graphics.

Comment: makes no sense to me, even after reading more than once: nothing "usually lags", there is neither an "empty variable" nor a "script". What's empty, though, is the code snippet.

Comment: Well I'm sorry if you didn't post your whole code. Guess you won't get Full help.